Removing or inactivating Podcast app on Catalina
For a while I have been experiencing issues with unwanted background activation of the Podcast application on my Mac mini running Catalina.
I realize that the app is "on" when the Mac suddenly slows down and RAM issues start. The app is not displayed as open in the Dock but I can see it as running when I open the Force Quit window. Once I click Force Quit the Mac goes back to normal.
It happens with no apparent reason, sometimes after boot up, and at other times while browsing, once every week, and not apparently induced by sort clicking some "podcast-associated" link/web.
Ive never used the app so it has no podcasts listed.
I understand that the genius at Cupertino made it a system app so it cannot be deleted (as in good old MacOS), so I wonder if there is a way to inactivate for good.

Welcome to Ask Different.
Technically, you can modify system volume files/applications even in the newest macOS versions, but it becomes a whole lot more complicated since macOS Big Sur (11.0) onwards. However, for Mac OS X Catalina (10.15), it is a little more easier. More on that later, but first...

1. Possible solution (recommended):
Personally, I think modifying the system volume files is like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Instead, I’d strongly encourage you first check if there’s any launch agent/launch daemon that is causing Podcasts app to run in the background?
To check this, run the command launchctl list in terminal and see if there’s any Podcast process that’s running (for example, it might be called com.apple.podcasts.PodcastContentService).
If you've found one, then just run launchctl unload com.apple.podcasts.PodcastContentService and it should unload the launch agent/launch daemon process for it. To check that it's been unloaded just run launchctl list again and check that you don't see the podcast process in the list. Note: If it fails to unload it, you may need to run the command using sudo, so for example, run sudo launchctl unload com.apple.podcasts.PodcastContentService. You'll be prompted to type your admin password to run the command using sudo.

2. Modifying the System Volume (NOT recommended)
If the above solution doesn't work, then there is a nuclear option involving modifying the system volume.
WARNING: Only perform the following tasks if you are comfortable with using terminal, disabling SIP and modifying system files. You should always back up your personal data as well. Modifying the system volume is a risk, so do it at your own peril.

Firstly, you'll need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) through recovery mode, see here for instructions, then reboot. Once you've rebooted back to normal, you will need to mount the system volume before making the necessary system changes (i.e. deleting podcasts app). To mount the System volume (after SIP has been disabled and you've rebooted back to normal), you need to enter the following commands in Terminal:
sudo mount -uw /
killall Finder

You will be prompted to enter your admin password for your Mac in order to run the sudo command.
Once you've run the above commands, the System Volume should change from Read only to Read & Write in Finder, allowing you to delete/move/copy the podcasts app and modify a whole slew of other system files all through Finder (i.e. no need to use Terminal for this part). Caution: Modifying system files/deleting applications can break other core functionality of macOS, so you might need to do some independent research on what consequences (if there are any) would deleting the podcast app have on your Mac.
Once you have finished making the changes, just restart your mac and the System volume should be unmounted by itself. Caution: SIP is still disabled, so if you are finished with modifying system files, you are strongly encouraged to enable SIP again by going into recovery mode and follow the reverse instructions as given in the above link.
Once all of that has been done, the podcast app will no longer be available on your Mac.
Note: There are a number of important caveats you should be aware of:

I don't believe there is a way to download and reinstall a single system app, so you'll most likely need to reinstall the entire operating system from scratch if you want to use the Podcasts app again at a later date.
Doing a minor software update (i.e. going from 10.15.1 to 10.15.2) might reinstall the Podcasts app again, but you can just follow the same process as above, as long as it is still in Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina.
However, if you were to install a major operating system release (i.e. going from Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina to macOS 11 Big Sur or macOS 12 Monterey, macOS 13 Ventura, etc.), then the Podcast app will reinstall itself and deleting/modifying system volume files is a whole lot more complicated in macOS 11+ due to the Signed System Volume (SSV) Apple introduced in macOS 11 Big Sur. More info about SSV can be found in Apple's support article here.

To modify System Volume files in macOS 11+, you will be required to disable SIP, disable the cryptographic verification, mounting the System Volume, make the required System Volume changes, then sealing/blessing a new snapshot of the System volume. Without blessing the snapshot of the System Volume's changes, the Mac will fail to boot until the snapshot has been blessed (I think you can do this within recovery mode though). More information on how does SSV interact with modifying System Volume files in macOS 11+ can be found in this blog.




In summary, I would first recommend you try the first possible solution, and check if there's a background process that is causing Podcasts to open. Then try unload the relevant process using launchctl unload command.
Failing this, then you can consider modifying the system volume, but I highly do not recommend you do this unless you are fully aware of the consequences of modifying system volume files, and be prepared to reinstall Mac OS X Catalina 10.15 from scratch if it affects the operating system after deleting podcasts app.
You should always back up all your data before modifying the system volume, because although it is unlikely to affect the data volume portion of your Mac's internal drive, you may need to reformat the entire internal drive when reinstalling Mac OS X Catalina (but this is really the worse case scenario).
Good luck!

First of all many thanks for your time and exhaustive answer. I followed your advice and started with the easiest procedure. launchctl list command returned me with "833 0 com.apple.podcasts.PodcastContentService". Then I tried to use your launchctl ("launchctl unload com.apple.podcasts.PodcastContentService") but it returned me unknown command error. I am quite sure it is just a synthax error in the above command (spacing or else)

Hmm, I think you need to unload the process using its file path. Having just looked at it in macOS Big Sur 11, it appears to be located in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PodcastServices.framework/XPCServices/... This might be the same file path as in Catalina, but to be honest, I wouldn't advise unloading processes located in the /System/ directory without getting some advice from others here who might have some more knowledge on the issue.

Besides, I suspect that PodcastContentService process isn't the likely cause for Podcasts app to be persistently opened. It's possibly something else that's causing the issue. So maybe wait until someone else has an answer here. In the interim, have you checked what login items you have in System Preferences>Users & Groups>Login Items? It may be that it was accidentally added to your login items, but this should technically show in your launchctl list...

Ok. Just to be more clear about the reported issue, Podcast is not persistently on. Sometimes it did (when the mac slows down) and it only appears in the force quit window, not in the application bar. That's why I thought there is something that sometimes for unknown reasons, "turn the app on without fully opened it" (I don't know how to describe it). Well, not a big deal, though. It seems specific for Catalina not having detected it in any other previous OS

The fact it's not showing up in your dock makes it sound like some sort of software error. Perhaps this bug was fixed in later macOS versions i.e. Big Sur? I certainly don't see any issues in Big Sur with it.

the latest OS accepted my Mac Mini 2012 is Catalina so I cannot say much about Big Sur. If no one reported it, seems an indication Catalina was only affected
